# Reproject big number of small geotiffs using gdal

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, gdalwarp

I have a large number of geotiffs (a few thousand), that are in a few different projections.  IE    EPSG:32628, EPSG:32629, EPSG:32630.  I would like to reproject the tiffs to 3857 so they are all in the same projection.  I am also serving them out as 3857 so I would save some time not reprojecting on the fly.

If I reproject each file on its own gdal is very fast.  However the tiffs do not mosaic together as the reproject leaves lines at the edges.

[image]

From the image above you can clearly see where the original tiffs were stitched together.

I have thought about using gdalwarp to create one giant image, but the processing might take days and I will likely end up with a tiff too big to handle.

Is there a way to reproject the individual tiffs but take into account surrounding tiffs when doing the reprojection so I don't end up with blank lines at the edges?

Comment: Add a screenshot about the artifacts that you have between the images.

Comment: It is slightly tricky but your artifacts should be NoData thereby easy to remove. You could create mini VRT files of up to 9 images, warp and then clip to a grid but still that's a lot of work. It might just be better to create a single VRT, get the projected extent and tile the output using gdalwarp -te xmin ymin xmax ymax in EPSG:3857. If you call subprocess.popen('gdalwarp -te {} {} {} {}...-multi..'.format(... you could perform a warp per pair of cores (8 cores = 4 processes). Would this sort of thing suit your purpose?